# how do I add elements/data on my two dimensional ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to make an inventory program, and i think it would be nice to make use of two dimensional ArrayList,

lets say i have an item code `String` "**001**" which will be stored on the first array index [0] and store the other datas on the other array since it's a two dimensional array, which contains the **item name, description, and price** also a `String`.

so its gonna look something like this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuQvJ.png

now, **how can I store all the data's and output all the the datas?**

thanks!

Comment: I think you need to give us more information about how your application is going to use this data, before anyone can recommend which data structure is best.

Comment: hmm, actually my application would just take an input from the user and print it. now, I'm confused lol. I'm a beginner sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a 2D array, or an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s.  Not all of your fields are of the same type.  I think you should make a class `Item` that has fields `name`, `description` and `price`, then make an `ArrayList` or an array of `Item`s.

Comment: At least, it didn't LOOK like they were all the same type, until you edited the question to tell us that "price" was a String.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is a `Map` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

A `List` is meant to hold items, but not to index them or make them easily searchable.  A `Map`, though, does just that.  Each item that gets put into a map has a key that uniquely identifies it.  Let's pretend that your product is named `Product`.  You could have a map like this:

```
Map<Integer, Product> map = new HashMap<Integer, Product>();
Product p = new Product("some name", "some desc");

// Put the item into the map
map.put(1, p);

// Get item back
Product sameAsP = map.get(1);
```